# How to implement form input validation in Angular 2

Tags: angular

How can I make these inputs to display a message such as "Name is required" when submitted(so the submit button is disabled until there is name inside) via Angular2 FormsModule?

```
<form class="">
    <div>
        <p>Name:</p>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="link-input">
        <p>City:</p>
        <input type="text">
    </div>

    <button 
        (click)="submitForm()">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html

Comment: [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)

Answer (score 2):

Follow this sample:

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(registerForm)"   novalidate>
    <div>
        <p>Name:</p>
        <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="link-input">
            <p>City:</p>
            <input formControlName="username" type="text">
                <em for="username" [hidden]="showError(registerForm.controls.name)" class="invalid">        You left this field blank or email format is not correct</em>

            </div>

            <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Component:

```
showError(field: FormControl){
        if(!field)
            return true;
        return field.valid || (field.pristine && !field.touched && !this.submitted)
    }

submitForm(f: NgForm) {
    this.submitted = true;
    if(!f.valid)
        return;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. what I'm trying to do is make the form validation template driven, is there a simple way to do that..? Sorry if I wasn't clear in the first place. As I understood, I need to add some properties in my existing form structure, and make functions for those in the app component. Also, my app component should import only FormsModule(not FormGroup, FormControl etc..), so I need a way to do it without those two imports

Answer (score 0):

Just add check if the form is valid otherwise disable the button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" [disabled]="!f.valid">Save to List</button>
```